# Cannot update a numeric error, Columns of type 'NUMERIC' cannot hold value of type 'CHAR'

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sql-update

so I'm trying to make a code to update a column in my table PATIENT. Unfortunately I cannot update a numeric column as I get an error saying:
Columns of type 'NUMERIC' cannot hold value of type 'CHAR'.

ANother error I get is that i cannot make an integer type as the WHERE clause, any thoughts?

Heres my code

```
private void updateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    try{


        Integer value0= Integer.parseInt(pat_id.getText());
        String value1= fName.getText();           
        String value2= lName.getText();
        Integer value3= Integer.parseInt(age.getText());

        String value4= (String)gender.getSelectedItem();
        String value5= address.getText();
        Integer value6= Integer.parseInt(home_number.getText());
        Integer value7= Integer.parseInt(mobile_number.getText());
        String value8= emer_cont_name.getText();
        Integer value9= Integer.parseInt(emer_cont_no.getText());

        String sql= "update PATIENT SET FNAME='"+value1+"', AGE='"+value3+"' WHERE PATIENT_ID='"+value0+"'";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record has been updated");
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    Update_table();
}
```

Comment: I ain't no sql expert but are you sure you should enclose numbers in single quotes?

Comment: One, please use descriptive variable names.  How can yo tell that 'value9' is your emergency contact for example?  Can you confirm that FNAME is declared with the right type?  Also, you should be using parameterized queries, as your current stuff is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @Joe Yes fname is declare with the right type, previous I tested the update with only fname and it was successful, its only when it comes to a numeric type I'm not sure how to work.

Comment: @user1724891 show us the table structure

Comment: @user1724891 are you sure that `value3` is not null ?

Comment: @Stephan

Table structure is ("CREATE TABLE patient (PATIENT_ID INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 10000, INCREMENT BY 1), FNAME VARCHAR(20), LNAME VARCHAR(20), AGE NUMERIC(3), ADDRESS VARCHAR(150), GENDER VARCHAR(10), HOME_NUMBER NUMERIC(10), MOBILE_NUMBER NUMERIC(10), EMER_CONT_FNAME VARCHAR(20),EMER_CONT_NO NUMERIC(10))");

Comment: @Stephan 100% sure, look at my code it set it to be the INTEGER value thats entered into my jTextField

Comment: @user1724891 its `Integer` not `int` so since its a object it CAN be null. Print the query before its executed.

Comment: @Stephan my apologises, the query? Is that the update statement because it's in the code. What it is updating is a set of values which have already been entered in the database, theres no code for this because i made a prepared statement for it. Rather I show you a screen shot

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1z6wjm&s=5

Comment: i mean you should put a breakpoint on the line `pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);` and see the value of `sql` variable, to see how the query is constructed

Answer (score 2):

Take out the single quotes that are around the 'value3' variable. Numeric values should not have them.